# onClick event not firing in echo statement with AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

Using this piece of code in the head of a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function vote() {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    } 

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'update.inc.php', true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

and this piece of html code:

```
<a id="vote" name="vote" onClick="vote();">Link</a>
```

Everything works properly when the link is clicked, update.inc.php is executed and it outputs to the screen. So i know the ajax is correct.

However, using this piece of php code

```
echo "<form>
        <input type=\"radio\" name=\"vote\"> yes
        <input type=\"radio\" name=\"vote\"> no
        <input type=\"button\" value=\"$count\" onClick=\"vote();\">
    </form>";
```

The function vote() no longer fires when i click the input button. What am I doing wrong in this echo statement?

Comment: Is there anything logged in the console when you click the button? Also note that the DTD's state that is should be `onclick` and not `onClick` (although this won't actaully break things)

Comment: You're missing a closing quote in the URL of `xmlhttp.open('GET', 'update.inc.php, true);`, check if that isn't a typo.

Comment: sorry im new to this an I dont know what you mean by console. Im using xampp with Apache to run the php files, and typically any errors are output to the page when it tries to load. Im not getting any errors there though

Comment: sorry about the quote typo, its been corrected. the ending quote actually is in the file im using though. I know that part of the code is working because when i use the link code to call the onclick event everything works fine

Comment: What does the actual source markup and code that PHP outputs to the browser? Meaning, from the source view in the browser.

Comment: What do you expect: the link to calling `vote()` to get the form with inputs... and then let the button call `vote()` again what's supposed to be sent?

Comment: the link portion is actually in a seperate file. I have to seperate php files, one has the link html in it, and its working. The other has the echo statement and it is not. But the ajax is exactly the same for both of them.

Comment: @StevePatterson The console is part of the browser, most browsers provide debuggin tools that can be accessed by pressing F12 on your keyboard while viewing the page. In there you will find a tab labelled "console", where you will see human readable error messages when something goes wrong.

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks for the info on the console, however f12 launches an addon for me. is there a menu way to get to it? Im using firefox

Comment: @StevePatterson [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) would be the tool for you, I think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your 2 radio buttons are named `vote` which is ambiguous between the function `vote` name and the name of your radios. So simply rename your function:

```
echo "<form>
        <input type=\"radio\" name=\"vote\"> yes
        <input type=\"radio\" name=\"vote\"> no
        <input type=\"button\" value=\"$count\" onClick=\"doVote();\">
    </form>";
```

and:

```
function doVote() {
    ...    
}
```

or rename your radio buttons if you prefer.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you try the code? Because I did. And guess what? This is the problem :-) Don't believe me? Here's the broken version for you: http://jsfiddle.net/bBYHR/1/, And here's the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/jaBq7/2/

Comment: PERFECT. It works now, thanks. Not exactly sure why it confuses a function call to the name of an input button but i guess it does.

Comment: OMG I have been writing Javascript for 6 years, how have I never known this and how has this never caused me a problem? I +1 this and hang my head in shame...

Comment: Also note that `id`s can also break the code - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/jaBq7/3/). This is the first time I see a `name` attribute breaking the code though, +1

Comment: Hang on, there must be more to this. I'm absolutely positive I would have run into this before now. Is it a function of quirks mode or something?

Comment: No, no quirks at all. It's one of the reasons why javascript is not an easy language to work with. Lots of things to know :-) There are so many gotchas. One of the reasons also why people wrote libraries such as jQuery.

Comment: I guess it's more to do with how HTML5 in some browsers allows accessing DOM elements directly in non-standard ways (without `document.getElementById`) - [try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/jaBq7/4/).

Comment: Unbelievable. I can only assume I have managed to avoid this nugget because I always do ids and classnames lowercase_with_underscores and I name everything in JS in camelCase (for vars and funcs) and TitleCase (for "classes") so I have never had a collision. I'm still stunned to have got this far without hitting this one though, and I'm going to call it a night because it makes me feel like I need a lie down... :-(

Comment: Interesting, the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/jaBq7/6/) also access DOM elements directly by name. I've only knew the `id`s issue because Firefox used to thrown a "DOM element referenced by ID without document.getElementById" or similar message in the console until not long ago. This seems to work with DTDs differently than HTML5 as well. @DaveRandom Yes, it's astonishing. `:P`